# no supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey) Putty

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty

Good evening everyone , I created an instance on my OvhCloud host, I followed the whole process from key generation to configuration of the instance detailed on this link: https://docs.ovh.com/fr/public-cloud/premiers-pas-instance-public-cloud/ Now I use Putty to connect to this instance created with the private key generated on PuttyGen. But I can't access my instance I get this error **(no supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey)**

I would like to know where the problem lies ???

Comment: In general questions/problems regarding the usability of or inaccuracies in HOWTO's and manuals should be addressed to their author and not posted on ServerFault. - Alternatively read our  [guide to writing good questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) and post an [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) question that contains sufficient details/errors/configuration-settings about **your setup** to provide you with a good solution, rather than confusing the issue with potential issues in both that guide and/or how accurately it was followed.